# Prove that $\sum^{P}_{k=1} \lfloor\frac {ka}{p}\rfloor = \frac{p^{2} - 1}{8} + \mu(a,p)$ mod$(2)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, quadratic-reciprocity

I can prove that $\sum^{P}_{k=1} \lfloor\frac {ka}{p}\rfloor = \mu(a,p)$ mod$(2)$ where $p$ is an odd prime, $P = \frac {p-1}{2}$, $a$ is an integer not divisible by $p$, and $\mu(a,p)$ is the quantity defined as the number of integers in the list $a, 2a, 3a, ..., Pa$ that become negative when the integers in the list are reduced modulo $p$ into the interval from $-P$ to $P$.

How do I show that, when $a$ is even instead of odd, and still not divisible by $p$,

$\sum^{P}_{k=1} \lfloor\frac {ka}{p}\rfloor = \frac{p^{2} - 1}{8} + \mu(a,p)$ mod$(2)$

is true?

Comment: Is the question clear?

Comment: This statement is a part of a very popular proof of quadratic reciprocity. It is usually proved geometrically by counting lattice points in triangles.

Comment: Yes, I understand and am aware of that proof. However, that proof relies on the first part of my question, the case for when a is odd, as a lemma.  Given that I can prove that, how would I show this for when a is even, as above?

Comment: Hmm. Usually in the proof, the two variables are $p$ and $q$, not $p$ and $a$, where $p$ and $q$ are both odd primes. I don't see any reason why a proof would require proving the case where $a$ is even.

Comment: Right, I think you're talking about the Einstein's proof of quadratic reciprocity, but I'm just referring to a lemma used along the way.

Comment: If you mean Eisenstein instead of Einstein, then yes you are right I am referring to that proof. However, I believe that the case of this lemma where $a$ is even is actually not necessary for the proof though.

Comment: I see, but this is still an exercise that was given to me and which I was told I should look into and understand, so I'd like to figure it out

Answer (score 0):

Using the last result I proved in your [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1483358/prove-%E2%88%91p%E2%88%921-2-k-1-left-lfloor-frac2akp-right-rfloor-equiv-%E2%88%91p/1769166#1769166), namely that for any odd prime $p$ and any natural number $b$ not divisible by $p$ we have:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\frac{p-1}{2}}\left\lfloor{\frac{2bk}{p}}\right\rfloor\equiv (b-1)\frac{p^2-1}{8}+\sum_{k=1}^{\frac{p-1}{2}}\left\lfloor{\frac{bk}{p}}\right\rfloor\text{ mod } 2$$

We can then set $b=a$ an even integer so that $(b-1)\equiv (a-1)\equiv 1 \text{ mod } 2$ which gives us:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\frac{p-1}{2}}\left\lfloor{\frac{2ak}{p}}\right\rfloor\equiv \frac{p^2-1}{8}+\sum_{k=1}^{\frac{p-1}{2}}\left\lfloor{\frac{ak}{p}}\right\rfloor\text{ mod } 2$$